# Inserted PDF not centered and creating empty pages

Tags: spacing, graphics, horizontal-alignment, pdf, includegraphics

I'm writing my bachelor's thesis and for this I'm working with Overleaf. I've uploaded my cover sheet as a PDF and want it to be on the very first page, directly before the abstract.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[page=1, scale=1]{Deckblatt.pdf}
\end{center}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\chapter*{Abstract}
...
\end{document}
```

I read an answer on here that the Package pdfpages is not necessary here as you can also just use the package graphicx and insert the pdf as a graphic. However, when I try to do this, the very first page is blank, the second one is actually showing the cover sheet, but it's heavily shifted to the right and you cannot read everything. Why does the \begin{center} command not fix this, and how do I do it instead?

Hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `\includepdf{file}` from *pdfpages* package and no `center`

```
\documentclass[]{}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[page=1]{Deckblatt.pdf}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\chapter*{Abstract}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot!